# how to force margin left to ion-button

Tags: css, sass, ionic4

im trying to positionate the buttons on left, but i cant make it responsive.
I want to do this:  [image: no]

here is my html:

```
<div class="teste">
  <div class="primeiro">
    <ion-button fill="clear">
      <span class="button-default">Parcialmente Exec.</span>
    </ion-button>
  </div>
  <div class="segundo">
    <ion-button fill="clear">
        <span class="button-default">Em aberto</span>
    </ion-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
  .card-header {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    border: blue 1px solid;
    .teste{
      margin-left: auto;
      border: red solid 2px;
    }
    .primeiro{
      border: purple solid 2px;
    }
    .segundo{
      border: orangered solid 2px;
    }
    ion-button {
      // margin-left: auto;
      height: 25px;
      max-width: 140px;
      border-radius: 12.5px;
      background-color: $warning;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
  }
```

this is what a i got so far [image: no again]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

> **`text-align: right;`** on **segundo** class.

*This makes the element in a parent align horizontally*

Answer (score 0):

Please this code..
For ion-button center position.

**css**

```
ion-button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

For ion-button left position.

```
ion-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```